# CakePHP: anyway to tell why Model->validates() returns false?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

If **Model->validates()** returns `false` is there an easy way to know why?

I am trying to save some data but it will not save. As it turns out, it is not validating either. If I turn off validation it saves. I need to validate it though, but I can not tell why it is not validating?

I used this code:

```
if($this->User->create($user) && !$this->User->validates())
{
    debug($user);
}
```

So if it doesn't validate it tells me what the data is.

It prints out this:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Tim
            [last_name] => Zahn
            [phone] => 8833323235
            [email] => t@z.com
            [password] => ert
        )

    [Confirm] => Array
        (
            [email] => t@z.com
            [password] => ert
        )

)
```

Which looks like it should be passing validation.

Also if needed I can post my Model source as well.

### Update:

Here is the model. I am using the [multivalidatable](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dardosordi/2008/07/29/multivalidatablebehavior-using-many-validation-rulesets-per-model) behavior. I have tried using the default and register validation sets:

```
class User extends AppModel
{
    var $actsAs = array('Multivalidatable');

    var $hasOne = 'WishList';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Address' => array(
            'conditions' => array('NOT' => array('Address.deleted' => '1')),
            'order' => array('Address.is_billing DESC')
        )
    );

    var $validate = array(
        'first_name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'last_name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'passRule1' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Please enter a password'
            ),
            'passRule2' => array(
                'rule' => array('identicalFieldValues', 'password'),
                'message' => 'Passwords do not match'
            )
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'emailRule1' => array(
                'rule' => 'email',
                'message' => 'You must specify a valid email address'
            ),
            'emailRule3' => array(
                'rule' => array('identicalFieldValues', 'email'),
                'message' => 'Emails do not match'
            )
        )
    );

    var $validationSets = array(
        'register' => array(
            'first_name' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty'
            ),
            'last_name' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty'
            ),
            'password' => array(
                'passRule1' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'Please enter a password'
                ),
                'passRule2' => array(
                    'rule' => array('identicalFieldValues', 'password'),
                    'message' => 'Passwords do not match'
                )
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'emailRule1' => array(
                    'rule' => 'email',
                    'message' => 'You must specify a valid email address'
                ),
                'emailRule2' => array(
                    'rule' => 'isUnique',
                    'message' => 'That email address is already in our system'
                ),
                'emailRule3' => array(
                    'rule' => array('identicalFieldValues', 'email'),
                    'message' => 'Emails do not match'
                )
            )
        ),
        'billing' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'emailRule1' => array(
                    'rule' => 'email',
                    'message' => 'You must specify a valid email address'
                ),
                'emailRule3' => array(
                    'rule' => array('identicalFieldValues', 'email'),
                    'message' => 'Emails do not match'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    public function beforeValidate()
    {
        parent::beforeValidate();

        // if password is empty reset from hash to empty string
        if (isset($this->data['User']['password']) && $this->data['User']['password'] == Security::hash('', null, true)) {
                $this->data['User']['password'] = '';
        }
        return true;
    }

    function identicalFieldValues($field=array(), $compare_field=null)
    {
        foreach ($field as $key => $value)
        {
            $v1 = $value;
            $v2 = $this->data["Confirm"][$compare_field];
            if ($compare_field == 'password' && $v2 != '')
            {
                $v2 = Security::hash($v2, null, true);
            }
            if ($v1 !== $v2)
            {
                return false;
            } 
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: What validation requirements have you set?

Comment: @cdburgess @Amy I have updated my Q to include my Model.

Comment: I would start by taking out the ValidationSets and see if it works. If it does, then it will narrow the issue down to the behavior.

Comment: @cdburgess, very good point, I'll try that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start with something like this:

```
if($this->User->create($user) && !$this->User->validates())
{
    debug($user);
    debug($this->User->validationErrors);
}
```

That should tell you exactly which field or fields aren't passing validation and why.

Comment: Yes `$this->User->validationErrors` Thats what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a message set up in the validation so it can tell you where it is failing, for example:

```
'password' => array(
  'rule' => array('minLength', '8'),
  'message' => 'Mimimum 8 characters long'
),
```

Also, if you have AUTH on, it may be encrypting the password.

Also, you should assert validate BEFORE you attempt to create/save.

Comment: I do have a message set in my validation rule, but in this particular instance I am not using a form to capture the data. I am using data saved in a session, (after sale complete) then telling user all they need to do is insert a password to create an account. So there is no form to display the message. Thats why I was wondering if there was a way to programmability capture the message. The output in the `debug` is not encrypted.

Comment: Actually it was because one of the passwords was getting encrypted and one wasn't so they weren't "matching" +1